# What is the package and background process for network time in Fedora 26?

Tags: fedora, process, gnome, time, ntp

Exactly the same question as this one, but for Fedora 26 in 2017:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/217463/what-is-the-package-and-background-process-for-network-time#232486

In Fedora 26 Workstation (Gnome), if you open 'All Settings' and then choose 'Date & Time' from the 'System' menu, there is an option for 'Automatic Date & Time' which requires Internet access.

What background process controls this? It doesn't seem to be ntpd. Is there a particular package associated with this feature?

(By the way, if there is a method to figure out the answer to a question like this, that would be nice to know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrony` is the default NTP client, offering better time synchronization on systems not always connected to the internet or on systems with unstable clocks.  It should be installed by default, and is found in the `chrony` package. You can still use the `ntpd` daemon from the `ntp` package if desired.  There are a few cases where you might want to do this (see the documentation link below).

The `chrony` daemon (`chronyd`) can be controlled at the command-line with `chronyc`.  For example, the available time sources configured can be seen with `chronyc sources`, much like you would use `ntpq -pn` with the classic NTP client.

The [chrony Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Understanding_chrony_and-its_configuration.html) provides a nice overview of `chrony` for Red Hat, CentOS and Fedora (of course). A successive chapter in the same document describes the classic [ntp](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Configuring_NTP_Using_ntpd.html) setup.  To use `ntp` you must disable `chrony`.